# Gatsby client only paths is showing 404 on first load in browser in production

Tags: firebase, gatsby, firebase-hosting

I am creating my dynamic pages in `gatsby-node.js` to create my client side paths. All pages are working fine in localhost, and pages are also showing desired data in production. But, still browser is showing the page as `404` on first load. I tried in `gatsby-node.js` in this way:

```
const path = require ("path")
exports.omCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions

    createPage({
       path: "/blog/id/slug",
       matchPath: "/blog/:id/:slug",
       component: path.resolve("src/components/Blogpage.jsx")
    })


    // Another try
    if (page.path.match(/^\app/)) {
       page.matchPath = "/blog/:id/:slug"

       createPage(page)
    }

}
```

Besides, I am using `firebase hosting`. I also tried configuring my `firebase.json` file for redirecting like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
     ...,
     "redirects": [
         {
            "source": "/blog/:id*",
            "destination": "/blog/:id/:slug",
            "type": 301
         }
     ]
  }
}
```

Comment: how does `blog/:id` gets resolved to `blog/:id/:slug`, where is the slug coming from in the redirect?

Comment: I edited the correct one, I missed the *, besides, I also tried with full "/blog/:id/:slug", but same

Comment: Do you think firebase is resolving all the URLs correctly? I faced the same issue with AWS S3 deployments.

Comment: I guess no. I am still getting 404 on first load. And after refreshing 404 doesn't come. And also page is always not found on Google search console

Comment: So if you move from `home` route to `blog` route it resolves perfectly but won't resolve on page refresh if the set url is that of a blog? Correct me if Wrong?

Comment: Okay, when I go to blog route, blog page is showing perfectly. But, if I inspect and check console, I see a 404 error. Then, I refreshe that same blog page, the 404 error is not showing further. I hope you got this

Comment: Can you share the minimum codebase?

Comment: Which part of codebase you want to see? I gave  my portion of code from `gatsby-node.js` and `firebase.json` file in my question

Comment: Try deploying it on Netlify, because without fullcode I won't be able to check the issue

Comment: I've got solutions. I needed to ise **rewrites** in `firebase.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got solution! 
All I need to do is, I must use **rewrites** in `firebase.json` file for defining my blog page in this way:

```
{
  "hosting": {
     ...,
     "rewrites": [
         {
            "source": "blog/**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
         }
     ]
  }
}
```

It works like charm.