# GatsbyJs firebase deployed website loads 404 before index

Tags: gatsby

When I deployed my website to firebase and load/reload the page, it will load the 404 page before the index one. You can barely see it because the transition goes pretty fast, but when you spam refresh you can clearly see it.

I tried to find anything related to this, but i couldn't. For now i deleted all the styling in 404 to hide it.

I've tried this so far, to redirect all routes to index.html and make it s.p.a website, but this doesn't stop the 404 page from loading first.

**Gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;
    if (page.path === `/`) {
      page.matchPath = `/*`;
      createPage(page);
    }
  };
```

I also tried a plugin `Disable 404` which breaks the build process.

Deleting the 404 is also not possible, so is there anything else i can do to prevent 404 to load?

Comment: Are you using any configuration to remove trailing slashes or to play with slugs?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I think it's an issue with firebase, because in development mode, i don't have it. I used the standard firebase config from documentation.

Comment: @FerranBuireu I found an answer for the issue, which says that when changing the route, it goes to the server to retrieve the page. But because i created a single page app in gatsby, i didn't create those pages (in the pages folder). So do I just create empty pages, or is there another way to do it?

https://lifesaver.codes/answer/getting-strange-404-before-page-loads

Comment: @FerranBuireu nvm, i tried to create the pages, but still get the 404 before. I'll probably look for another hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting the Firebase host configuration (`rewrites`). In your firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
     ...,
     "rewrites": [
         {
            "source": "/",
            "destination": "/index.html"
         }
     ]
  }
}
```

Modified from: [Gatsby client only paths is showing 404 on first load in browser in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62002377/gatsby-client-only-paths-is-showing-404-on-first-load-in-browser-in-production)

Comment: This works well for routes like /test, but only when i created it in pages. As a single page application, it's not working. When i go to /test and refresh i'm still getting the 404 on my spa.

Comment: What about using `"source":"**"` in that case?

Comment: that's the default configuration i think and that did not work for me. I think it will be easier to look for another host i guess